# user post has an external link. how do i create an href out of that link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm working with rails at the moment and Ive come across the problem of my users having posts with external links, I would like the link to be automatically generated. I have no idea of where to even start, I have googled, and searched on stackoverflow but I cant seem to find anything. It may be that I just don't know how to search this specific topic.

Comment: `<%=link_to nil,"http://www.google.com"%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [auto_link](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) or [Rinku](https://github.com/vmg/rinku) gems. They can scan string and replace urls with `<a></a>` block

Comment: perfect! thats all i was looking for. do you know of any tutorials as far as Rinku goes? it's not very explicit in its directions on github.

Comment: I don't. But it looks like auto_link repo is more active, so you might want to try it instead. As far as I know it directly mimics rails auto_link helper that was removed from rails in v3.1 - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link